# Why all div will go open If am clicking on any one button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the data to show the content as the frontend side. In this image [image]
you can see I have mentioned the button with the div attributes i.e. in blue color.I tried the below code but I don't know how to create/handle the button and div.

```
import React from "react";
import {Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./style.scss"

class Example extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opencollapse: true,
    }
  }

  toggle = () => this.setState((currentState) => ({opencollapse: !currentState.opencollapse}));


  renderApps = () => {
    const result = this.props.userdata.appliers.map((item, i) => {
      return(
        <div key={i}>
          <div>
            <div className="d-flex">
              <Col>
                <button onClick={this.toggle}>{this.state.opencollapse ? 'Click to close' : 'See Letter'}</button>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                  helloIcon
              </Col>              
            </div>
            {this.state.opencollapse && <div>{this.props.userdata.appliers[i].letter}</div>}
          </div>
      </div>
      )
    });
    return result;
  }

  render(){

    return (
        <div>
          {this.renderApps()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

I don't know where I did wrong.

In the image as you can see I tried to click on the number three button to open the third div but number 1 and number 2 button is also getting opened. I want to open those div which is opened by me, others let be closed. If I will click on button number one then div number one should be open and the rest should be closed vice versa.

Comment: You use only one state variable for that class and that applied to the three buttons, so those three will just follow what that state value...

Comment: It's because they all share the same state

Comment: @Reyno How can we share at different state?

Comment: @DhanaD. How can I use different state variable for different class ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have the same state variable for all buttons.
You can create another component.
Then each mapped component will have its own state

Child Component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./style.scss"

class ChildExample extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opencollapse: true,
    }
  }

  toggle = () => this.setState((currentState) => ({opencollapse: !currentState.opencollapse}));

  render(){

    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className="d-flex">
              <Col>
                <button onClick={this.toggle}>{this.state.opencollapse ? 'Click to close' : 'See Letter'}</button>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                  helloIcon
              </Col>              
            </div>
            {this.state.opencollapse && <div>{this.props.text}</div>}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ChildExample;
```

renderApps function in Example component:

```
renderApps = () => {
    const result = this.props.userdata.appliers.map((item, i) => {
      return(
         <ChildExample text={this.props.userdata.appliers[i].letter}
      )
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good solution would be to create a seperate component for your button and the content its hiding. This way we can give each component their own state.

A simplified example can be found below:

```js
class ToggleElement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      opencollapse: true,
    };
  }
  
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState((currentState) => (
      {opencollapse: !currentState.opencollapse}
    ));
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>{this.state.opencollapse ? 'Click to close' : 'See Letter'}</button>
        {this.state.opencollapse && <div>{this.props.item.letter}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  
  renderApps() {
    return this.props.data.map((item, i) => (
      <ToggleElement item={item} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderApps()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={[
    {letter: 'A'},
    {letter: 'B'},
    {letter: 'C'},
  ]} />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your buttons have same state, you can try to create a different state for each button, or create an array of refs with your divs with content and connect this array to your buttons via some data-index and then open the only one div that matched to button's index

Comment: Sorry, I am not well aware of this field. How can we create a code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the state as array of states instead of one.

For example:

- The state on constructor

  ```js
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      let initOpenCollapse = [];
      const n = 5; // This is set based on how many buttons you want to create
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) initOpenCollapse.push(true); 
      this.state = {
        opencollapse: initOpenCollapse,
      }
  }
  ```
- The toggle function

  ```
  toggle = (nthButton) => {
    let resultState = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.opencollapse.length; i++) {
        if (i === nthButton)
          resultState.push(!this.state.opencollapse[i]);
        else
          resultState.push(this.state.opencollapse[i]);
    } 
    this.setState((currentState) => ({opencollapse:  resultState}));
  };
  ```
- And in the `render()`:

  ```
  <button onClick={() => this.toggle(i)}>{this.state.opencollapse[i] ? 'Click to close' : 'See Letter'}</button>
  ...
  ...
  {this.state.opencollapse[i] && <div>{this.props.userdata.appliers[i].letter}</div>}
  ```

Comment: And what if there is n number of buttons then? what would be the code for `    this.state = {
      opencollapse: [true, true, true],
    }`

Comment: You may need to generate an array length `n` of `true` above the `this.state = ...`

Comment: @Kwall Edited the snippet. Please check

Comment: Still, all button is showing their respective div content whenever I am clicking on any button.

Comment: @Kwall I forgot to set the check on the `<button>` to the array state

Comment: Now the issue is when I clicking on button one, the second div is getting open, on button two, the third div getting open and so on.. what error would be there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236091/discussion-between-dhana-d-and-kwall).