# Use "this" keyword to toggle per section and not all sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an open/close component that is applied to multiple sections.

```
export default function Expand() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const expand = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
```

Later in my code I have this (EDITED):

```
 {sections.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <button
                onClick={expand}>
                <h2>{item.heading}</h2>
```

And then:

```
{open && ( <div>Text when you open</div> ) }
```

Problem is that the multiple sections all open/close when clicking just one section. I need that when you click section one, only section one opens/closes. Then when clicking section two, only section two opens/closes.

I figure that I have to use `this` keyword but with my current code I don´t see where to add. Where to add to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think this post applies, but I cannot make it work with my code... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817150/why-all-div-will-go-open-if-am-clicking-on-any-one-button

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword is irrelevant here. You cannot use a single state value to keep track of expended state of multiple sections; you need an array of states.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const sections = ['s1', 's2', 's3'];
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(Array(sections.length).fill(false));

  const toggleOpen = (index) => {
    const newIsOpen = [...isOpen];
    newIsOpen[index] = !newIsOpen[index];
    setIsOpen(newIsOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {sections.map((item, i) =>
        <div key={i}>
          <button onClick={() => toggleOpen(i)}>Toggle section {item}</button>
          {isOpen[i] && <div>{item}</div>}
        </div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I see, I was stuck on the `this` keyword. I updated my code because I have code that maps through the section items.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom hook `useExpand` like

```
export default function useExpand() {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState('closed');
    const expand = (sectionName)=>setIsExpanded(sectionName);
    return [isExpanded, expand];
}
// And the in the component use the hook:
export function Component() {
    const [isExpanded, expand] = useExpand();
    // your code...
    {sections.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            <button
                onClick={()=>expand(item.heading)}>
                {item.heading}
            </button>
         </div>
         )}
}
// and finally to actually expand ...
{isExpanded === item.heading && ( <div>Text when you open</div> )}
```

Comment: Obviously this is assuming the `item.heading`s are unique. If you need to also close it, add a second boolean param to the `expand` hook, like
```//...  
const expand = (sectionName, status) => setIsExpanded(status?sectionName:'closed');
```

Comment: thanks, I like this solution but I am stuck on this error... Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Very difficult to diagnose without seeing the code